# Laravel: unable to find font dependencies

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I have a fresh installation of Laravel, and I can't get `npm run dev` to successfully run:

> These dependencies were not found:
>
> - bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
>     in
>     ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> - bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>     in
>     ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> - bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
>     in
>     ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> - bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>     in
>     ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
> - bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
>     in
>     ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Browsing the Internet for answers, I found issue [#289 on Github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/289) but the fix proposed doesn't work:

Last line of _variables.scss:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
```

App.scss:

```
// Fonts
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600);

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

@import "_app";
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems to me that fix should work. My guess it that it's a load order issue. Where are you `@import`ing the variables file?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys, I've updated my question. It just above the bootstrap include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by reverting to the previous version of *package.json*. You can find it here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c1643bf0c59b6864fc55e09cce3bfafc67d29e2a/package.json